# What is the syntax for using throw exception overloads (without using the new() constructor/method)?

Tags: powershell, exception

I can't actually recall which specific exception sparked this question, but I've seen at least 1x exception that had a `new()` constructor in .NET Framework (PS 5.1) but not .NET (PS 7) -- or maybe it was the other way around? -- and required me to use the syntax

`throw [<ExceptionClassHere>] "My Exception Message."`

rather than

`throw [<ExceptionClassHere>]::new("My Exception Message.")`

In the case(s) where you want to use a constructor overload using the first syntax example above, how do you pass multiple arguments?

Comment: not possible. for multiple arguments you need to invoke the ctor.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I think this actually *works* by design (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77904651/1701026))

Comment: @iRon yes, casting is by design when the type has a 1 argument ctor or the type implements the `.Parse` method, or the type implements the `op_Explicit` method among others but OPs question is how to cast targeting an overload that has more than 1 argument (which is not possible)

Answer (score 2):

Since PowerShell v3, if a type has a default constructor and settable property that accepts a string, you do not need to use the `new()` method to construct an instance.
Meaning that instead of:

```
[FormatException]::new("My Exception Message.")
```

You might just attach the argument to the class:

```
[FormatException]"My Exception Message."
```

As the expression in [`throw [<expression>]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_throw) can also be an object, the syntax to do this is actually more neat than you might expect:

```
Throw [FormatException]"My Exception Message."
```

Yields in PowerShell (Core):

> ```
> OperationStopped: My Exception Message.
> ```

Yields in Windows PowerShell (5.1):

> ```
> My Exception Message. At line:1 char:1
> + throw [FormatException]"My Exception Message."
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FormatException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : My Exception Message.
> ```

Comment: Just wanted to add that the output differs slightly (in both pwsh and PowerShell) when using "throw" from a script vs the command line.  This answer is helpful although, as Santiago mentioned, I was wondering about passing multiple arguments rather than taking advantage of a default ctor.  I haven't found any native .NET exception classes where the default ctor requires multiple args (yet).